# camelCase parameters in setter in PhpStorm

Tags: jetbrains-ide, intelinde

I have under_score named properties in my class like `transaction_id` or `web_order_item_id`. And I want to customize the parameter name in my setters when I generate it.

For now it generate this:

```
/**
 * @param int $original_transaction_id .camelCase()
 */
public function setOriginalTransactionId(int $original_transaction_id): void
{
    $this->original_transaction_id = $original_transaction_id;
}
```

But I want this:

```
/**
 * @param int $originalTransactionId .camelCase()
 */
public function setOriginalTransactionId(int $originalTransactionId): void
{
    $this->original_transaction_id = $originalTransactionId;
}
```

I have tried to change this behavior in **Settings/Editor/File and Code Templates/Code/Php Setter Method** but I couldn`t found ability to do it.
There is a variable in the template:

```
${NAME}
```

But it returned value in this form **$OriginalTransactionId** instead **$originalTransactionId**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Apache Velocity StringUtils here, like

```
#set($Setter_param = ${StringUtils.removeAndHump(${PARAM_NAME})})
#set($Setter_param = $Setter_param.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + $Setter_param.substring(1))

/**
 * @param ${TYPE_HINT} $${Setter_param}
 */
public ${STATIC} function set${NAME}(#if (${SCALAR_TYPE_HINT})${SCALAR_TYPE_HINT} #end$${Setter_param})#if (${VOID_RETURN_TYPE}):void #end
{
#if (${STATIC} == "static")
    self::$${FIELD_NAME} = $${Setter_param};
#else
    $this->${FIELD_NAME} = $${Setter_param};
#end
}
```

Comment: that is  what I wanted. Thank!